# How to create JSON format string in iphone?

Tags: iphone, json, string-formatting

I want to create JSON string like {"search_element": "New York"} this. I used following code for that.

```
 NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"search_element\":""\"%@\"""}",
                            [searchName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

After doing this I am getting value like {"search_element":"New%20York"} this. I want it should be New York instead New%20York. I am not getting How to format it for expected result.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply call next

```
    NSString *newString = [JSONString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@""];
```

However look into [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) and [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) ..they have methods to make valid JSON in iOS

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use it like that?

```
NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"search_element\":""\"%@\"""}", searchName];
```

So basically without the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method

And I don't really understand why do you use that:

```
@"{\"search_element\":""\"%@\"""}"
```

I'd do it with less quotation marks:

```
@"{\"search_element\":\"%@\"}"
```

Did a quick test:

```
NSString *test = @"{\"search_element\":\"%@\"}";
NSLog(test, @"New York");
```

output:

`{"search_element":"New York"}`

Hope it helps

Comment: You got me wrong. Novarg u conside New York hard core value. I want it should be enter by user. It may be anything. Do u know any other way to do this. If u know please tell me.

Comment: then try the following: `NSLog(test, someTextField.text);` where in that `someTextField` is user's input